# Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function, in this function i will write

```
<script type='text/JavaScript' language='JavaScript'>alert('ha')</script>
```

But while executing this page it doesn't work. This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function asd()
{
 document.write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('asdasd');</" + "script>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="asd();">
 <span id="gdfg"></span>
 <span>dgdfghfghfghfg</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code worked when I tested in in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: `document.write` is [illegal](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite) in XHTML documents (served as `application/xhtml+xml`). The `language` attribute of `script` elements is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT). Moreover, it's a bad practice to do things this way. Just use more standardized DOM manipulation functions. That said, not bad you separated `</` and `script>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Rafael meant was this

```
window.onload=function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = '/myalert.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

or

```
window.onload=function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  var textNode = document.createTextNode('alert("bla");')
  script.appendChild(textNode)';
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: I really can't imagine a case where the second example could be useful. Can you?

Comment: This example code is indeed not very useful, but it's just a question and the author may be working with more complex code.

Comment: Yes, I only gave the second example to allow the construct of the original question without judging what the need could be. For example extracting script from an ajax reply

Answer (score 2):

Don't use document.write after the page has loaded, cause it will reset the whole document.
If you want to add some new elements (like <script> tags) to the document, use DOM (document.createElement, element.appendChild, etc.).